# How to use java8 stream operations to select only one element from each key in the map after grouping by two fields?

Tags: java-8, stream, grouping

I have a list of Person having multiple fields.

I need to group by two of these fields. (age and name)

So the result I get will be a map of map like:

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, List<Person>> result;
```

now I need to remove the second key in the result, and also reduce the list to a single person. (which means I need to group all the persons by age, then have a list of Persons with different names for that same age.)The rules to select the persons of the same name are defined in a function like
Person reduce(List persons){}
Currently my code looks like this:

```
Map<Integer, List<Person>> select(List<Person> persons){

    Map<Integer, Map<string, List<Person>> result = 
        persons
        .stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(p -> p.getAge(),
                    groupingBy(p -> p.getName(),
toUnmodifiableList())   // HERE
                    // CAN WE REPLACE "toUnmodifiableList()" with something
                    //related to "selectPerson" method to simplify the flow?
                )
        );

    return result
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(this::ignoreName)
            .collect(toUnmodifiableMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue))
}


Map.Entry<Integer, List<Person>> ignoreName(Map.Entry<int, Map<String, List<Person>>> persons){
    List<Person> ps = 
           persons
            .getValue()
            .values()
            .stream()
            .map(this::selectPerson)
            .collect(toUnmodifiableList());
    return AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(persons.getKey(), ps);
}

Person selectPerson(List<Person> persons){
    ///...
}
```

**Now my question is, is there a way to simplify this? by doing something directly inside the downstream of groupingBy?**

```
Example:
Person1: personID 1, age 24, name john
Person2: personID 2, age 24, name anna
Person3: personID 3, age 25, name mike
Person4: PersonID 4, age 25, name mike 
Person5: PersonID 5, age 25, name bob

Map<Integer, Map<String, List<Person>>>:
24 -> john -> personID 1
   -> anna -> personID 2
25 -> mike -> personID 3
           -> personID 4
   -> bob  -> personID 5
Expected Result:
Map<Integer, List<Person>>:
24 -> personID1
   -> personID2
25 -> personID 3 or 4, depending on selectPerson logic
   -> personID 5
```

Comment: This code will not compile. We cannot use primitives as type parameter.

Comment: In your `select` method, How can you expect to return a `Map<Integer, Person>` when two people may have the same age?  It would have to be `Map<Integer, List<Person>>`.  And in your `selectPerson` method  you are returning a `Person` without passing criteria on what to base the selection.

Comment: @WJS, thanks for the reply. You are right. it should be a list. the reason is just I can't put my work code here so I made up this person class.